# Configuration file with untrackable parts

Tags: git, file, configuration

I've got a configuration file containing some configuration important for the whole project (ie: anybody who clones the repository should have this same conf), and some local configuration (anybody who clones the repository could need to  customize something in this file, and I don't want to track local customization).

This file is unique: I cannot configure the software to use multiple files, and it doesn't support any kind of `include` directive.

Is there any way to handle this scenario with Git?

---

I could use `git-add -p` or `-i` to only stage part of this file, but it's not a good solution: it's too error prone, requires quite some work and `git-status` will always display this configuration file as locally modified.

Maybe I could use some git hooks?

Comment: Could you check in a config template "configname.template" with only the correct global options set, then ask your users to copy it to the real config name? They need to set the local options anyhow, so asking this of them should not be a lot of extra hassle.

Comment: @Janne: that's what I'm doing at the moment: I've got a `config.global` (tracked) and a `config.local` (untracked) file. Users have to modify only `config.local` and to run `cat config.global config.local > config` anytime one of the two gets modified. Problem is that in this way the configuration file isn't actually tracked by git and users have to explictly care about when `config.global` is updated and to manually update their `config` file. This scenario, also, is quite error prone.

Comment: So the global config is prone to change as well? I'm afraid I don't see a good way to deal with this from git. You could resort to something like having a wrapper script around the real appliction that first checks for changes in the global config file and merges it with the local config before handing over to the application proper. Not exactly elegant but at least you remove an error-prone manual intervention.

Comment: @Janne: yes, both local and global config files needs to be changed sometimes. I was hoping that this could be achieved with some git hooks that would exclude from tracking some lines marked in special ways. The solution of having a wrapper script for the software is nice, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Have a "config.global" and a "config.local" file for your checked in global config and the local user-specific parts. Make a wrapper script for the application (how, exactly, will depend on the OS of course). Have the script first check for modification time of the global, local and "real" config file. If either partial file is newer, concatenate them into the real config. Then start the application proper.

Answer (score 0):

There really is no way to track part of a file in git that I know of.

You could modify the code to load the main file, and then one customized for the environment that overrides the defaults. Developers can keep their own custom version, and you might also use the custom one for differences in test/dev/prod etc...

Comment: I'd love I could do that. Unfortunately the software I'm relying on is closed source and doesn't support multiple configuration files...

Comment: I see, that's too bad. Good luck!